# UITextView in UITableViewCell missing last line in read-only mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` containing a few cells. I am using iOS 8.0 and `UITableView` is set up in automatic mode. The layout seems fine as height is ok for all cells and content.

Only thing I can't understand is why as soon as I reload `UITableView` for the second time the last line of the `UITextView` disappears. I know the text is properly setup (I use nslog to check what is stored in `UITextView`) but last line is not displayed. `UITextView`s have the following setup:

```
[uitextview setScrollEnabled:NO];
[uitextview setEditable:NO];
[uitextview setUserInteractionEnaled:NO];
[uitextview setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

Also if I put scrolling allowed then I can see full text when scrolling... Is it something that has been noticed by someone else before? I'll try to add screenshots later. Also note it is ok with one line but from two lines then last line will disappears ...

Thanks.

EDIT1/

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *cellIdentifierNotif = @"Notif";
        NotifTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierNotif];

        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[NotifTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifierNotif];
        }

        [cell.labelTitle setBackgroundColor:[[self.myNotif objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"bgcolor"]];
        [cell.labelTitle setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"New comment(s) in '%@'",[[self.myNotif objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"title"]]];

        return cell;
}
```

EDIT2/

I think it is worth to say that it is working fine on iphone 5 but not on iphone 6 (simulator & real device tested).

[image: iphone5]
[image: iphone6]

EDIT3/

Maybe worth to say that the uitableview is in a view that gets hidden / unhidden regularly. Also worth to say that the first time it is unhide I am pretty sure i see the full text for a 10th of a second before it disappears ...

Comment: What's your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` look like? Also, your rows/section?

Comment: Is your tableview cell's height shrinking?

Comment: I added some more info that should help. the cellforrowatindexpath is very classic as you can see.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue was coming from my constraints which are screen size dependent and my calculations with iphone 6 and 6+ were giving "strange numbers" (quarter of a point for example which is not handled by the system) so the automatic layout was not able to compute properly and the small height missing made the last line disappear ... I'll post details later.

Comment: Never did hear back!